# meanjs route to server controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, meanjs

i am trying to add a new method to my controller "matches.server.controller" names listTeams.
I have added a new route to the matches.server.route.js file  like this

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller'),
matches = require('../../app/controllers/matches.server.controller');

module.exports = function(app) {
// Match Routes
app.route('/matches/listTeams')                 <-- new route added here !!
    .get(matches.listteams);


app.route('/matches')
    .get(matches.list)
    .post(users.requiresLogin, matches.create);


app.route('/matches/:matchId')
    .get(matches.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, matches.hasAuthorization, matches.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, matches.hasAuthorization, matches.delete);

// Finish by binding the matches middleware
app.param('matchId', matches.matchByID);
};
```

this is the method in my server controller:

```
exports.listteams = function(req, res) {
    res.json(1);
};
```

In matches.client.controller i call the method like this:

```
 $scope.listteams = function(){
        $scope.teams = Matches.get('matches/listTeams').success(function(data){
            var d = data;
        }).error(function(data){
            var d = data;
        });
```

however when i debug i always come in the list method of matches and not in listTeams method
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: as I understood you are using [meanjs.org](http://meanjs.org/)

Comment: Why have you screwed this controller? To receive array of teams from MongoDB?

Comment: The reason why i "screwed this controller" is because the teams are not in mongodb but i want to get them from a web service.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you are duplicating the path name

All parameters that goes after `'/matches/'` is handling by

```
app.route('/matches/:matchId')
    .get(matches.read)
    .put(users.requiresLogin, matches.hasAuthorization, matches.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, matches.hasAuthorization, matches.delete);
```

and perceiving like argument of`'/:matchId'`

In your case: `find me team with id "listTeams"`

Try to rename your path from `matches` to smth else like

```
module.exports = function(app) {
// Match Routes
app.route('/smthelse_not_matches/listTeams')   <-- new route added here !!
    .get(matches.listteams);
```